# Examples of Continuous Functionals and Operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, integral-operators

I am currently working trough the chapter 2.10 in the book "Spectral Theory of Self-Adjoint Operators in Hilbert Space" (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-009-4586-9).
This chapter works with integral operators of the form
$(Tu)(x)=\int_Yt(x,y)u(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)$
where first the following definition is introduced:

If the kernel $t(x,y)$ satisfies the two following conditions
1.The integrand $(Tu,v)=\int_{Y\times Y}t(x,y)u(y)\overline{v(x)}\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(y)<\infty$ is summable for all $u,v\in H$
2.The sesqui-linear form defined in the integral above is bounded.
then $T$ is called a regular integral operator.

$\underline{\mathrm{Question\,1}}$
Is condition 2 not just a weaker form of condition 1? Because $||\Phi||=||T||=\sup_{||x||, ||y||=1}|\Phi(x,y)|=\sup_{||x||, ||y||=1}|(Tx,y)|<\infty$ is just a special case of condition 1.

$\underline{\mathrm{Question\,2}}$
In the Proof of Theorem 1:
Let H=$L_2(Y,\mu)$ and let $t(x,y)$ satisfy
$a_1=\sup_y\int_Y|t(x,y)|\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<\infty$ and $a_2=\sup_x\int_Y|t(x,y)|\mathrm{d}\mu(y)<\infty$,
then T is an regular integral operator and $||T||^2\leq a_1a_2$.
the following step occurs
$|(Tu,v)|^2 = |\int_Y \int_Y t(x,y)u(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(y) \overline{v(x)} \mathrm{d}\mu(x)|^2$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\leq \int_{Y \times Y} |t(x,y)|\cdot|u(y)|^2 \mathrm{d}\mu(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(x) \cdot \int_{Y \times Y} |t(x,y)|\cdot|v(y)|^2 \mathrm{d}\mu(y)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)$.
The author sais the Cauchy inequality has been used but I don't see how.
If I use Cauchy the following expression emerges
$|(Tu,v)|^2\leq ||Tu||^2\cdot ||v||^2$. Here the kernel $t(x,y)$ only appears in one of the Integrals not both of them.

I was able to proof that $||T||^2\leq a_1a_2$ in a different way however, it is necessary for me to understand the "trick" (as the author himself calls it on page 54 under equation 11) that is used, since most of the proofs in this chapter use the same one.

The secound problem I have is that I do not see how the $T$ is regular, as Theorem 1 only shows $||T||^2\leq a_1a_2$ which fulfills only the secound part of the definition "regular" but not the first one. But this problem should be closely related to question 1.

Thank you very much in advance!
Henrie

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say nothing about what $Y$ nor $H$ are, but it is probably the case that $Y$ is a measure space, and $H=L^2(Y)$.

Condition 2 is stronger than condition 1. They are equivalent, though, because if you start with 1 you can get to 2 via the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Theorem).

As for Cauchy-Schwarz, let $S$ be the operator with kernel $|t(x,y)|^{1/2}$. Then
\begin{align}
|(Tu,v)|^2& = \Big|\int_Y \int_Y t(x,y)u(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(y) \overline{v(x)} \mathrm{d}\mu(x)\Big|^2\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\bigg[ \int_Y \int_Y |t(x,y)|\, |u(y)|\,  |v(x)|\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)\bigg]^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\bigg[ \int_Y \int_Y |t(x,y)|^{1/2}\, |u(y)|\,\   |t(x,y)|^{1/2}|v(x)|\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)\bigg]^2\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\bigg[ \int_Y \int_Y |t(x,y)|\, |u(y)|^2\,\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)\bigg]\bigg[ \int_Y \int_Y |t(x,y)|\, |v(x)|^2\,\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)\bigg].\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

Comment: Yes my bad. You are right of corse. $H$ is the Hilbert space of the measurable functions on $Y$.

Comment: In that case I will have to take a look at the Uniform Boundedness Principle. But isn't condition 2 just condition 1 with the restriction that $||u||=||v||=1$? Or where am I mistaken?

As for the integration: everything is clear up until the last step. I will try to prove it and if I don't get it done I will ask again.

Comment: No. Condition 2 says that the bound is **uniform** on $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$, which condition 1 doesn't say.

Comment: Hello again, could you elaborate on the last step from above? It looks to me as if you use Hölder inequality but I don't quiet get how to use it in the double integral. Thank you.

Comment: @HenrieKüppers: $$\int_{Y\times Y} A(x,y)B(x,y)\,d(\mu\times\mu)\leq \bigg(\int_{Y\times Y}|A(x,y)|^2\,d(\mu\times\mu)\bigg)^{1/2}
\bigg(\int_{Y\times Y}|B(x,y)|^2\,d(\mu\times\mu)\bigg)^{1/2}
$$
Any integral of a product of functions gives you a positive sesquilinear form and Hölder applies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. So the Hölder inequality on double Integrals works the exact same way. Do you nkow by any chance if there exists a proof somewhere? The double integrations confuse me if i try to write it down explicitely.

Comment: Hölder inequality holds for the Lebesgue integral in any measure space. The proof is always the same: all it uses is that integrals are linear and positive. For the same reason, any proof of Cauchy-Schwarz applies. If is clearer if I write it like this? $$\int_Z |A\,B|\,d\lambda\leq \bigg(\int_Z |A|^2\,d\lambda\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\int_Z |B|^2\,d\lambda\bigg)^{1/2}.$$ All I did is call $Z=Y\times Y$ and $\lambda=\mu\times\mu$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  So there are no significant way you could unravel your transformation in the last line of the post above that could clarify what I am doing wrong in the post below?

Comment: It is not obvious at all, to me, why the expression you wrote would be less than the right-hand-side you are aiming for.